# Bird seed for Robins and Tits

Tags: bird-feeding, robins

Do Robins like the mixed seed bird food I can buy from the garden centre? What bird feeder should I use for Robins and Tits?

Comment: "*the* mixed seed bird food I can buy from *the* garden centre". Please be more specific; you are writing for a world wide audience here.

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14880/best-food-to-attract-blue-tits

Comment: American robins ( thrushes) generally do not eat seeds. American titmice are seed eaters , they seem to prefer sunflower seed , not the typical cheap millet mixes.

Comment: American robins or "old-world" robins? Completely different birds, including what they eat. As @blacksmith37 noted, American robins are not seedeaters.

Comment: @blacksmith37, that's interesting. Although they prefer insects, our American robins eat seeds and bits of suet that have fallen from birdfeeders, usually the smaller type, like nyjer seeds. They don't eat at any of our 19 different feeders, however.

Comment: Suet is generally eaten by bug eaters like woodpeckers.. I have never seen anything but Goldfinches and Pine Siskins ( occasionally) on the nijer feeders.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much any, the bird feeds you get from the garden centres are normally very informative, you can see what to feed different birds for different seasons. If you get a multi-feeder, so basically a pole you can hang different types of feeders on you can accommodate a range of birds.

You can however get Robin specific feeders, take a look here: [RSPB bird feeders](https://shopping.rspb.org.uk/suet-feeders/i-love-robins-feeder.html?mediacode=T17PPC0036&gclid=Cj0KCQiA-JXiBRCpARIsAGqF8wXzeB6WqY0aK4ySdUO_MDNR0KrMhSTSoB3KHIDj9iWr7Z6XdpflCoIaApkfEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) - they have a natural diet of protein-rich mealworms, energy-rich seeds and soft fruits. So you can put out peanut paste coconut shells, mealworms, half an apple etc without needing a feeder.

Tits will use a variety of feeders, from peanut to seed, so whatever you set out for a robin should be fine. Take a look at this related answer: [Best food to attract blue tits](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14880/best-food-to-attract-blue-tits)